# Check if last character in series is upper case and convert to lowercase if true

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I have a column of strings that look similar to the following:

```
1          IX-1-a
2          IX-1-b
3          IX-1-C
4          IX-1-D
```

Some end in lowercase letters while others end in uppercase. I need to standardize all endings to lowercase without affecting the letters at the beginning of the string. Below is some code fragment that I am working with to make changes within the series but it doesn't quite work.

```
if i in tw4515['Unnamed: 0'].str[-1].str.isupper() == True:
      tw4515['Unnamed: 0'].str[-1].str.lower()
```

How can the truth table from `tw4515['Unnamed: 0'].str[-1].str.isupper()` be utilized efficiently to affect conditional changes?

Comment: You don't need the `if`. Just convert the last letter of the entire column to lowercase. If it's already lowercase it has no effect.

Comment: sometimes the simple solutions go completely unnoticed, lol. thank you for pointing that out. I thought there may be other cases in my data that could complicate things but its all fine on my end.

i'm happy to accept your comment as the answer if you want to re-write as an answer.

Comment: I don't actually know the best syntax to do this in Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to split once from the right side, make the second part lowercase, then combine:

```
tmp = s.str.rsplit('-', 1)
out = tmp.str[0] + '-' + tmp.str[1].str.lower()
```

If the last part is always a single letter, [@Barmar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71875571/check-if-last-character-in-series-is-upper-case-and-convert-to-lowercase-if-true/71875615#comment127011318_71875571) is even better:

```
out = s.str[:-1] + s.str[-1].str.lower()
```

Output:

```
1    IX-1-a
2    IX-1-b
3    IX-1-c
4    IX-1-d
```